Is this the correct way to express primality in Martin-Löf type systems?
I am self studying type theory from the HoTT book.  More or less as a way to test that I have the right idea I'm trying to see if I can express the idea of "Primes" in the theory.  This is what I worked out.
$$ \sum_{a:\mathbb{N}}\prod_{b,c:\mathbb{N}}(a=b\cdot S(S(c))) \rightarrow (b = 1) $$
I am using the successor function twice on c so that multiplier is never 0 or 1 thus avoiding the definition including 1 as a prime number.

It depends on whether you want a type of all prime numbers or a type (depending on the natural numbers) that tells you whether a number is prime. The type you written out is more or less the type of all prime numbers and it seems valid to me. In this intro to HoTT book https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.11082#, the author defines a type $is-prime(n)$. The approach in this book is a little bit different from yours.

There is a definition of primes in Rijke's Introduction to HoTT, section 8.5.

The definition is correct, I'm not sure what else to elaborate on. If you want, you could write the usual isPrime : Nat -> Bool function and prove that your definition is equivalent to it.
